# Why does Mysql not start when inside of $ /usr/local/mysql/bin on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: mysql, command-line, osx-lion

I installed mysql on my Mac, and for some reason when I am inside the folder with the executables, it does not start mysql, but when putting /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u username -p it does. Is there a reason for this, or is it only happening to me? I am running Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The /usr/local/mysql/bin folder is most likely not in your path.

Do a `echo $PATH` and check it out for yourself to make sure

Comment: But I thought it did not matter if I was inside of that same folder. So if I were to have done ./mysql I could have accomplished the same thing?

Comment: Correct, if you are in the folder you need to do `./mysql` Regular `mysql` will still search the path

Comment: Ahh, thanks a lot!! That makes a lot of sense now. So it will always traverse the paths first. I do have one other question if you don't mind. Everywhere it says the $PATH is located in .profile. But my mac does not have one. When I echo $PATH tho, I still see the default one. When I add it in .bashrc, it puts it in front of the default one that is not in a file. Where is the default path??

Comment: Sure, you can specify your own `.profile` file that will be your user's unique path but the default one is loaded in `/etc/profile` I believe

Comment: The proper way to change your path though would be through `.profile` or `.bashrc`, you probably shouldn't be changing the one in /etc/profile fyi

Comment: Oh yes, I am aware. It was bothering me that I did not know where it was. I really appreciate the answers!

Comment: So I looked, and it is not in there. But I guess I will look around and explore the file system.

Comment: I just checked on my version of OSX 10.7 and found that it actually calls an executable here `/usr/libexec/path_helper` that seems to construct the path, at least that's as far as I can tell

Comment: Hmm, so the question is where are the default paths held... It's weird that I cannot find it with just the text I am looking for. When using export on the command line(no editor), where is the path placed. Maybe its there. I checked /etc/paths, and it looked like it, but it was missing /usr/X11/bin